# Can i connect in pin of relay module to Analog pins of arduino instead of digital pin?

Tags: arduino-uno, relay, electronics, analogwrite, electricity

Im a complete beginner

Im making a project using relay modules and arduino. but all the digital pins of my arduino are filled.
I wanted to ask if i can use the analog pins to connect my relay module to my arduino? If yes can anyone give me the statements to write high and low using analog.

Comment: pins that have analog functionality are multi purpose ... they can also be used for digital outputs ... the command is the same for all digital output pins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can  use the analog pins as digital pins.
Quoting this [Arduino tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Foundations/AnalogInputPins):

```
pinMode(A0, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(A0, HIGH);
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the code snippet for digital input:

```
pinMode(A0, INPUT);
digitalRead(A0);
```

Comment: Your answer is certainly correct, but it would be better to show an example of using an analog pin as a digital INPUT, since that's what the OP is asking about.

Comment: worked for me thanks